# How to implement row detail feature in Jquery Datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using Jquery DataTable plugin to display all the database records and want to use the row details feature of Jquery DataTable. I am able to display the records within Jquery DataTable using web service and now I want that when a user clicks on any ID, the row should drop down and further I want to display more records of that particular ID within that expanded row in a tabluar format along with any image if present. Please guide me how can I implement this.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function format(d) {
        return 'Full name: ' + d.FirstName + ' ' + d.LastName + '<br>' +
    'Department: ' + d.DEPARTMENT + '<br>' +
    'The child row can contain any data you wish, including links, images, inner tables etc.';
    }
var dt;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'EmployeeService.asmx/GetEmployees',
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                   dt = $('#datatable').dataTable({
                        data: data,
                        'scrollY': 200,
                        columns: [
                        {
                        "class":"details-control",
                        "orderable":      false,
                        "data":           null,
                        "defaultContent": ""
                        },
                    { 'data': 'ID' },
                    { 'data': 'FirstName' },
                    { 'data': 'LastName' },
                    { 'data': 'DEPARTMENT' },
                    { 'data': 'AGE' },
                    { 'data': 'Salary' },
                    { 'data': 'Address' },
                    ],
                    "order": [[1, 'asc']]
                });
                // Array to track the ids of the details displayed rows
                var detailRows = [];
            $('#datatable tbody').on('click', 'tr td.details-control', function () {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var row = dt.row(tr);
                var idx = $.inArray(tr.attr('id'), detailRows);

                if (row.child.isShown()) {
                    tr.removeClass('details');
                    row.child.hide();

                    // Remove from the 'open' array
                    detailRows.splice(idx, 1);
                }
                else {
                    tr.addClass('details');
                    row.child(format(row.data())).show();

                    // Add to the 'open' array
                    if (idx === -1) {
                        detailRows.push(tr.attr('id'));
                    }
                }
            });

            // On each draw, loop over the `detailRows` array and show any child rows
            dt.on('draw', function () {
                $.each(detailRows, function (i, id) {
                    $('#' + id + ' td.details-control').trigger('click');
                });
            });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="border:1px solid black; padding:3px; width:1000px;">
    <table id="datatable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Department</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
    <th>DateOfJoining</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>EMPImage</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Department</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
    <th>DateOfJoining</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>EMPImage</th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Web Service**

```
[WebMethod]
        public void GetEmployees()
        {
            string CONStrng = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constrng"].ConnectionString;
            List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CONStrng))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetEmployee", con);
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 50;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    Employee employee = new Employee();
                    employee.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]);
                    employee.FirstName = dr["firstname"].ToString();
                    employee.LastName = dr["lastname"].ToString();
                    employee.DEPARTMENT = dr["department"].ToString();
                    employee.AGE = Convert.ToInt32(dr["age"]);
                    employee.Salary = dr["salary"].ToString();
                    employee.DOJ = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["JoiningDT"]);
                    employee.Address = dr["address"].ToString();
                    employee.IMAGE = dr["empimage"].ToString();
                    employees.Add(employee);
                }
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(employees));
        }
```

**JSON Response-**

```
[{"ID":1,"FirstName":"Ashish","LastName":"Kumar","SSN":111,"DEPARTMENT":"IT","AGE":25,"Salary":"18000","MartialStatus":"Single","Address":"Garia"},{"ID":2,"FirstName":"Abhishek","LastName":"Kumar","SSN":112,"DEPARTMENT":"IT","AGE":26,"Salary":"18000","MartialStatus":"Single","Address":"Garia"},{"ID":3,"FirstName":"Joy","LastName":"Das","SSN":113,"DEPARTMENT":"Operations","AGE":25,"Salary":"20000","MartialStatus":"Married","Address":"Garia"},{"ID":4,"FirstName":"Abir","LastName":"Chakraborty","SSN":114,"DEPARTMENT":"Marketing","AGE":29,"Salary":"40000","MartialStatus":"Single","Address":"Birati"},{"ID":5,"FirstName":"Priyanko","LastName":"Dey","SSN":115,"DEPARTMENT":"IT","AGE":28,"Salary":"15000","MartialStatus":"Single","Address":"Dhakuria"},{"ID":6,"FirstName":"Shamik","LastName":"Ghosh","SSN":116,"DEPARTMENT":"Export","AGE":35,"Salary":"40000","MartialStatus":"Married","Address":"Bali"},{"ID":7,"FirstName":"Sree Mohan","LastName":"Nathani","SSN":117,"DEPARTMENT":"Accounts","AGE":40,"Salary":"42000","MartialStatus":"Married","Address":"Girish Park"},{"ID":8,"FirstName":"Asis","LastName":"Dingal","SSN":118,"DEPARTMENT":"Accounts","AGE":39,"Salary":"30000","MartialStatus":"Married","Address":"Garia"},{"ID":9,"FirstName":"Sankar","LastName":"Kapuria","SSN":119,"DEPARTMENT":"Maintenance","AGE":32,"Salary":"10000","MartialStatus":"Married","Address":"Panskura"},{"ID":10,"FirstName":"Rahul","LastName":"Bannerjee","SSN":120,"DEPARTMENT":"HR","AGE":25,"Salary":"15000","MartialStatus":"Single","Address":"Kalighat"},{"ID":11,"FirstName":"Rekha","LastName":"Prasad","SSN":121,"DEPARTMENT":"Data Entry","AGE":28,"Salary":"8000","MartialStatus":"Single","Address":"Lake Town"},{"ID":12,"FirstName":"Pramod","LastName":"Modi","SSN":122,"DEPARTMENT":"Director","AGE":62,"Salary":"50000","MartialStatus":"Married","Address":"Garia Hat"}]
```

Comment: Check **[this](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html)** and **[this](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)** examples

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Hi Mr. Rao I have gone through this sample only, even I have applied this solution but the problem is I am not able to expand my row.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Please check my code I have followed the same process as explained in the link you provided me. But here I am getting an error which says Uncaught TypeError: dt.row is not a function. Please guide me.

Comment: The scope of your `var dt` is inside `ajax success`.. Declare `var dt` somewhere outside and then just assign it in `success` as `dt = $('#datatable').dataTable({`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: I have done as u suggested but now I am getting this error- Uncaught TypeError: dt.row is not a function on this line
`var row = dt.row(tr);`

Comment: Can you post your json response in **[`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net)**?

Comment: Here is the **[`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/4g0fzesw/1/)** generated by the sample `json` you've given.. The method is bit changed.. Try using the method given in fiddle instead of `$.ajax`..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: Mr. Rao the fiddle u provided works fine but the problem is that I am generating the Json data using WebService. I have mentioned in my question the webservice I have made which is giving me exact json I require.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: There is also a difference between ur json data and my json data.
your json data starts with {"data":[ {..},{..},.....{..} ] }
where as my json data starts with [ {..},{..},....{..} ]
Does this makes difference? If so then how? Please guide me how can I rectify this?

Comment: You can google on how you can get this structure.. Its very simple.. and I believe there are lot of posts explaining this.. If you wont get any then I'll try it out once..